# C# How to read an entire div class in a html page source

Tags: c#, html, parsing

I would like to read the following page source in `C#`: [www.joindota.com/en/start/](http://www.joindota.com/en/start)

I need to read the matchticker on the side, however, in the page source that is available but the divs etc are all the same for the rest, how do I differentiate? To explain my question better by example:

```
<div class="item_head swap" onclick="matchticker_toggle_coverage(1596)">
                <span style="float: right;" >19:00h</span>
                <div class="item_head_swap item_head_swap_open" id="matchticker_coverage_arrow_1596"></div>
                The Defense
            </div>

            <div id="matchticker_coverage_content_1596" >
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16561-mtw-vs-westernwolves" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/se.gif" border="0" alt="se" title="Sweden" /> mTw</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/fr.gif" border="0" alt="fr" title="France" /> Wolves</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span title="Wed, 25.01.2012, 21:00 CET">
                                                                            25.01.                                                                  </span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16553-evil-geniuses-dota-vs-mousesports-dota" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/eu.gif" border="0" alt="eu" title="Europe" /> EG</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/eu.gif" border="0" alt="eu" title="Europe" /> Mouz</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span title="Wed, 25.01.2012, 19:30 CET">
                                                                            25.01.                                                                  </span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16627-sk-gaming-dota-vs-just-4-the-tournament" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/dk.gif" border="0" alt="dk" title="Denmark" /> SK</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/de.gif" border="0" alt="de" title="Germany" /> J4T</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span title="Tue, 24.01.2012, 21:00 CET">
                                                                            24.01.                                                                  </span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16554-problem-vs-natus-vincere" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/fi.gif" border="0" alt="fi" title="Finland" /> Prob?</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/ua.gif" border="0" alt="ua" title="Ukraina" /> NA`VI</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span title="Tue, 24.01.2012, 19:30 CET">
                                                                            24.01.                                                                  </span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16545-evil-geniuses-dota-vs-natus-vincere" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/eu.gif" border="0" alt="eu" title="Europe" /> EG</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/ua.gif" border="0" alt="ua" title="Ukraina" /> NA`VI</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span title="Sun, 22.01.2012, 19:00 CET">
                                                                            3h 21m
                                                                                                            </span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16546-team-dignitas-dota-vs-mousesports-dota" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/ro.gif" border="0" alt="ro" title="Romania" /> Digni</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/eu.gif" border="0" alt="eu" title="Europe" /> Mouz</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span class="ticker_score_win">1</span>:<span class="ticker_score_loss">0</span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16624-mtw-vs-just-4-the-tournament" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/se.gif" border="0" alt="se" title="Sweden" /> mTw</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/de.gif" border="0" alt="de" title="Germany" /> J4T</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span class="ticker_score_loss">0</span>:<span class="ticker_score_win">1</span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16676-fnatic-msi-vs-problem" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/rs.gif" border="0" alt="rs" title="Serbia" /> Fnatic</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/fi.gif" border="0" alt="fi" title="Finland" /> Prob?</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span class="ticker_score_win">1</span>:<span class="ticker_score_loss">0</span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16622-westernwolves-vs-just-4-the-tournament" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/fr.gif" border="0" alt="fr" title="France" /> Wolves</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/de.gif" border="0" alt="de" title="Germany" /> J4T</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span class="ticker_score_win">1</span>:<span class="ticker_score_loss">0</span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16539-natus-vincere-vs-mousesports-dota" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/ua.gif" border="0" alt="ua" title="Ukraina" /> NA`VI</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/eu.gif" border="0" alt="eu" title="Europe" /> Mouz</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span class="ticker_score_win">1</span>:<span class="ticker_score_loss">0</span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16538-evil-geniuses-dota-vs-fnatic-msi" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/eu.gif" border="0" alt="eu" title="Europe" /> EG</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/rs.gif" border="0" alt="rs" title="Serbia" /> Fnatic</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span class="ticker_score_win">1</span>:<span class="ticker_score_loss">0</span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16537-mtw-vs-panzer" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/se.gif" border="0" alt="se" title="Sweden" /> mTw</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/de.gif" border="0" alt="de" title="Germany" /> PANZER</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span class="ticker_score_loss">0</span>:<span class="ticker_score_win">1</span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16536-team-dignitas-dota-vs-problem" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/ro.gif" border="0" alt="ro" title="Romania" /> Digni</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/fi.gif" border="0" alt="fi" title="Finland" /> Prob?</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span class="ticker_score_win">1</span>:<span class="ticker_score_loss">0</span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16398-team-epidemic-vs-just-4-the-tournament" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/eu.gif" border="0" alt="eu" title="Europe" /> EPD</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/de.gif" border="0" alt="de" title="Germany" /> J4T</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span class="ticker_score_loss">0</span>:<span class="ticker_score_win">1</span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.joindota.com/en/matches/16498-absolute-legends-vs-sk-gaming-dota" class="item">
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 18px; text-align: left;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/themes/joindota/ticker_9.png" border="0" alt="" /></div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/au.gif" border="0" alt="au" title="Australia" /> aL</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 20px;">vs.</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="width: 103px;"><img src="http://www.gs-media.de/img/flags/dk.gif" border="0" alt="dk" title="Denmark" /> SK</div>
                        <div class="sub" style="float: right; text-align: right;">
                                                            <span class="ticker_score_loss">0</span>:<span class="ticker_score_win">1</span>
                                                    </div>
                        <div class="cl"></div>
                    </a>
                                            </div>
```

The values change all the time, like the team vs team as well as the date and time. How would I be able to read this all into one string that would output something like this to the console:

`The Defense: mTw vs. Wolves [Wed, 25.01.2012, 21:00 CET] - EG vs. Mouz [Wed, 25.01.2012, 19:30 CET]` etc

Those values change every day, like the teams, dates, etc. But the

How would I be able to read that entire div class for "The Defense", and output those specific details I need to the console in a string or something? I don't know how I would go about doing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out HTML Agility Pack for parsing HTML documents, and navigating / transforming them using LINQ.

Comment: Isn't there a webservice API available to retieve that data? That might make everything easier persistent. I mean, they can change their layout anytime.

Comment: @Aidiakapi Unfortunately not. :( But I will be trying out HTML Agility pack, thanks for the replies everyone.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I'd use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), it uses [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) to let you navigate to the node you want, and then you can extract the exact node you like.

Comment: Another vote for agility pack - I've used it to great success